# WinRE Command Prompt does not show any drives

Tags: windows-10

I am running a perfectly normal, updated, copy of Windows 10 Home on my Dell Inspiron 5402. I can see all my drives and partitions as normal.

I boot into WinRE by doing RESET + SHIFT

I go into `Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Command Prompt`

In the Command Prompt I can't find my Windows 10 `C:` drive.

I go into `diskpart` and run `list disks` and I get

```
There are no fixed disks to show
```

The WinRE Command Prompt would be kind of pointless if my drives are not accessible. What am I doing wrong?

One weird thing, that may be related, is that it does not ask me to login to my account when I open WinRE. I think it's supposed to do that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending an entire freaking weekend on this, I finally figured it out. It's because the Dell BIOS uses "Intel Rapid Storage Technology" to enable RAID configuration.

However, the Dell `WINRETOOLS` windows recovery partition did not have the drivers required to use the Intel RST VMD controllers -- therefore, it could not load/read the hard drives.

So the solution is as follows:

1. Use Diskpart to assign the Dell `WINRETOOLS` partition to a drive
2. Find the `winre.wim` file and mount it using DISM
3. Download and add the Intel RST VMD controller drivers to the image
4. Save the image and boot into Windows Recovery Environment, it should work now.

My problem is specific to Dell, but this could potentially happen to any manufactures that has custom drivers for their hard disk controller. (Saw someone with an HP having similar issues)

I hope someone finds this information useful!