# WinRE missing storage drivers

Tags: drivers, windows-re

I have a few systems that I need to make some changes using the command prompt in the recovery environment however the command prompt does not see any internal drives.

I have found another [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1652092/winre-command-prompt-does-not-show-any-drives/1653050) asked on here that seems promising but the systems that are afflicted do not have a `winre.wim` on them. I've mounted all the partitions to search for it. We use a custom image for deployment sometimes and I think the original Dell OEM partitions were deleted during deployment. I can find the image file on my system easily.

The computers can boot into the recovery environment, so there must be some instance that the `winre.wim` is somewhere? How can I find that image so that I can inject the drivers into it?

Comment: Not an answer (thus the comment).  Do you actually need winre?  I myself would probably use a pre-configured winpe like [hiren's](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/)

Comment: Security prefers that I don't use Hiren's...